# can not open console view in eclipse neon 2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I am trying for display console menu but I can't succeed.
select too many times in windows => Show View => Console in Menubar. but it can not open in eclipse window. 
[check this Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWfws.png)

I can use server view but can not open Console view.
I already click on a console in windows option but I was failed.
please give me a solution.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see "Quick Access" text box on top right corner. Just type "console" there and enter and see if it works.

Comment: Can you try resetting the perspective? Window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective...

Comment: which eclipse version are you using?

Comment: eclipse neon 2.

Comment: \workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi stores the workbench state. May be that's corrupted.  You may try to exit eclipse, rename this file and restart eclipse. New workbench.xmi file will be created at same location and may possible resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if it has opened console on the right? If yes, then you can drag it to the bottom.